# Date, time, and GPS metadata tagging video for iOS

Tags: ios, geolocation, metadata, exif

On 2019/10/16 (last Wednesday), I went skydiving in Las Vegas which they recorded but the provided video was in 10 seperate clips and none had time or GPS metadata tagged. I want these as 1 video on my iPhone which is ordered chronologically and displayed on the map correctly.

For the single video, I've used OpenShot to concatenate the 10 clips.

For the date, time, and location, I:

1. Have tried looking for iOS apps that can add geotag / GPS metadata information to **videos** (not photos) but seemingly none exist.
2. Have tried using [Video GeoTagger](https://videogeotagger.com/) but that didn't work at all.
3. Am trying to use [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

Obviously, I needed the GPS information which I got using https://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm

For ExifTool, I have referenced the documentation ([link 1](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=5977.0), [link 2](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q14), [link 3](https://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html#Examples))), used command `& "PATH\exiftool.exe" -groupnames -s "PATH\Video 17-10-2019, 15 03 25.mov"` to get the metadata / tags of a video that was recorded on the iPhone and works as intended, and formulated the following command:

```
& "PATH\exiftool.exe" `
"-xmp:gpslatitude=35 56 57.2 N" `
"-xmp:gpslongitude=114 51 28.3 W" `
"-QuickTime:CreateDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00" `
"-QuickTime:ModifyDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00" `
"-QuickTime:TrackCreateDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00" `
"-QuickTime:TrackModifyDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00" `
"-QuickTime:MediaCreateDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00" `
"-QuickTime:MediaModifyDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00" `
"-QuickTime:CreationDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00-07:00" `
"-QuickTime:GPSCoordinates=35 56 57.2 N, 114 51 28.3 W, 660.00 m Above Sea Level" `
"-Composite:GPSLatitude=35 56 57.2 N" `
"-Composite:GPSLongitude=114 51 28.3 W" `
"-Composite:GPSPosition=35 56 57.2 N, 114 51 28.3 W" `
"-Composite:GPSAltitude=660.00 m" `
"-Composite:GPSAltitudeRef=Above Sea Level" `
"PATH\Skydive_OpenShot_ExifTool_Test.mp4"
```

This outputs the following:

```
Warning: Sorry, Composite:GPSLatitude doesn't exist or isn't writable
Warning: Sorry, Composite:GPSLongitude doesn't exist or isn't writable
Warning: Sorry, Composite:GPSPosition doesn't exist or isn't writable
Warning: Sorry, Composite:GPSAltitude doesn't exist or isn't writable
Warning: Sorry, Composite:GPSAltitudeRef doesn't exist or isn't writable
    1 image files updated
```

(The Composite errors seems to be because they're dynamically generated as... a composite of other tags.)

In my iPhone's Photos app, the date and time are correct but the GPS / location information is not available.

Full tags of the various files below:

**Original MP4** file (wrong date and time, no GPS):

```
[ExifTool]      ExifTool Version Number         : 11.71
[File]          File Name                       : Skydive_OpenShot.mp4
[File]          Directory                       : .
[File]          File Size                       : 577 MB
[File]          File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:10:16 12:00:00+01:00
[File]          File Access Date/Time           : 2019:10:21 08:19:52+01:00
[File]          File Creation Date/Time         : 2019:10:21 08:19:21+01:00
[File]          File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
[File]          File Type                       : MP4
[File]          File Type Extension             : mp4
[File]          MIME Type                       : video/mp4
[QuickTime]     Major Brand                     : MP4  Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]
[QuickTime]     Minor Version                   : 0.2.0
[QuickTime]     Compatible Brands               : isom, iso2, avc1, mp41
[QuickTime]     Movie Data Size                 : 604417274
[QuickTime]     Movie Data Offset               : 48
[QuickTime]     Movie Header Version            : 0
[QuickTime]     Create Date                     : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
[QuickTime]     Modify Date                     : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
[QuickTime]     Time Scale                      : 1000
[QuickTime]     Duration                        : 0:05:12
[QuickTime]     Preferred Rate                  : 1
[QuickTime]     Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
[QuickTime]     Preview Time                    : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Preview Duration                : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Poster Time                     : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Selection Time                  : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Selection Duration              : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Current Time                    : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Next Track ID                   : 3
[QuickTime]     Track Header Version            : 0
[QuickTime]     Track Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
[QuickTime]     Track Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
[QuickTime]     Track ID                        : 1
[QuickTime]     Track Duration                  : 0:05:12
[QuickTime]     Track Layer                     : 0
[QuickTime]     Track Volume                    : 0.00%
[QuickTime]     Image Width                     : 1920
[QuickTime]     Image Height                    : 1080
[QuickTime]     Graphics Mode                   : srcCopy
[QuickTime]     Op Color                        : 0 0 0
[QuickTime]     Compressor ID                   : avc1
[QuickTime]     Source Image Width              : 1920
[QuickTime]     Source Image Height             : 1080
[QuickTime]     X Resolution                    : 72
[QuickTime]     Y Resolution                    : 72
[QuickTime]     Bit Depth                       : 24
[QuickTime]     Video Frame Rate                : 29.973
[QuickTime]     Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
[QuickTime]     Media Header Version            : 0
[QuickTime]     Media Create Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
[QuickTime]     Media Modify Date               : 0000:00:00 00:00:00
[QuickTime]     Media Time Scale                : 48000
[QuickTime]     Media Duration                  : 0:05:12
[QuickTime]     Media Language Code             : und
[QuickTime]     Handler Description             : SoundHandler
[QuickTime]     Balance                         : 0
[QuickTime]     Audio Format                    : mp4a
[QuickTime]     Audio Channels                  : 2
[QuickTime]     Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
[QuickTime]     Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
[QuickTime]     Handler Type                    : Metadata
[QuickTime]     Handler Vendor ID               : Apple
[QuickTime]     Encoder                         : Lavf57.83.100
[Composite]     Image Size                      : 1920x1080
[Composite]     Megapixels                      : 2.1
[Composite]     Avg Bitrate                     : 15.5 Mbps
[Composite]     Rotation                        : 0
```

**ExifTools-modified MP4** file (correct date, correct time, no GPS):

```
[ExifTool]      ExifToolVersion                 : 11.71
[File]          FileName                        : Skydive_OpenShot_ExifTool_Test.mp4
[File]          Directory                       : .
[File]          FileSize                        : 577 MB
[File]          FileModifyDate                  : 2019:10:22 13:07:23+01:00
[File]          FileAccessDate                  : 2019:10:22 13:07:23+01:00
[File]          FileCreateDate                  : 2019:10:22 12:28:02+01:00
[File]          FilePermissions                 : rw-rw-rw-
[File]          FileType                        : MP4
[File]          FileTypeExtension               : mp4
[File]          MIMEType                        : video/mp4
[QuickTime]     MajorBrand                      : MP4  Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]
[QuickTime]     MinorVersion                    : 0.2.0
[QuickTime]     CompatibleBrands                : isom, iso2, avc1, mp41
[QuickTime]     MovieHeaderVersion              : 0
[QuickTime]     CreateDate                      : 2019:10:16 12:00:00
[QuickTime]     ModifyDate                      : 2019:10:16 12:00:00
[QuickTime]     TimeScale                       : 1000
[QuickTime]     Duration                        : 0:05:12
[QuickTime]     PreferredRate                   : 1
[QuickTime]     PreferredVolume                 : 100.00%
[QuickTime]     PreviewTime                     : 0 s
[QuickTime]     PreviewDuration                 : 0 s
[QuickTime]     PosterTime                      : 0 s
[QuickTime]     SelectionTime                   : 0 s
[QuickTime]     SelectionDuration               : 0 s
[QuickTime]     CurrentTime                     : 0 s
[QuickTime]     NextTrackID                     : 3
[QuickTime]     TrackHeaderVersion              : 0
[QuickTime]     TrackCreateDate                 : 2019:10:16 12:00:00
[QuickTime]     TrackModifyDate                 : 2019:10:16 12:00:00
[QuickTime]     TrackID                         : 1
[QuickTime]     TrackDuration                   : 0:05:12
[QuickTime]     TrackLayer                      : 0
[QuickTime]     TrackVolume                     : 0.00%
[QuickTime]     ImageWidth                      : 1920
[QuickTime]     ImageHeight                     : 1080
[QuickTime]     GraphicsMode                    : srcCopy
[QuickTime]     OpColor                         : 0 0 0
[QuickTime]     CompressorID                    : avc1
[QuickTime]     SourceImageWidth                : 1920
[QuickTime]     SourceImageHeight               : 1080
[QuickTime]     XResolution                     : 72
[QuickTime]     YResolution                     : 72
[QuickTime]     BitDepth                        : 24
[QuickTime]     VideoFrameRate                  : 29.973
[QuickTime]     MatrixStructure                 : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
[QuickTime]     MediaHeaderVersion              : 0
[QuickTime]     MediaCreateDate                 : 2019:10:16 12:00:00
[QuickTime]     MediaModifyDate                 : 2019:10:16 12:00:00
[QuickTime]     MediaTimeScale                  : 48000
[QuickTime]     MediaDuration                   : 0:05:12
[QuickTime]     MediaLanguageCode               : und
[QuickTime]     HandlerDescription              : SoundHandler
[QuickTime]     Balance                         : 0
[QuickTime]     AudioFormat                     : mp4a
[QuickTime]     AudioChannels                   : 2
[QuickTime]     AudioBitsPerSample              : 16
[QuickTime]     AudioSampleRate                 : 48000
[QuickTime]     HandlerVendorID                 : Apple
[QuickTime]     Encoder                         : Lavf57.83.100
[QuickTime]     GPSCoordinates                  : 35 deg 56' 57.20" N, 114 deg 51' 28.30" W, 660 m Above Sea Level
[QuickTime]     HandlerType                     : Metadata Tags
[QuickTime]     CreationDate                    : 2019:10:16 12:00:00-07:00
[QuickTime]     MovieDataSize                   : 604417274
[QuickTime]     MovieDataOffset                 : 277799
[XMP]           XMPToolkit                      : Image::ExifTool 11.71
[Composite]     ImageSize                       : 1920x1080
[Composite]     Megapixels                      : 2.1
[Composite]     AvgBitrate                      : 15.5 Mbps
[Composite]     GPSAltitude                     : 660 m
[Composite]     GPSAltitudeRef                  : Above Sea Level
[Composite]     GPSLatitude                     : 35 deg 56' 57.20" N
[Composite]     GPSLongitude                    : 114 deg 51' 28.30" W
[Composite]     Rotation                        : 0
[Composite]     GPSLatitudeRef                  : North
[Composite]     GPSLongitudeRef                 : West
[Composite]     GPSPosition                     : 35 deg 56' 57.20" N, 114 deg 51' 28.30" W
```

**iPhone-recorded MOV** file (correct date, time, and GPS):

```
[ExifTool]      ExifTool Version Number         : 11.71
[ExifTool]      Warning                         : [minor] The ExtractEmbedded option may find more tags in the movie data
[File]          File Name                       : Video 17-10-2019, 15 03 25.mov
[File]          Directory                       : .
[File]          File Size                       : 171 MB
[File]          File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:10:20 17:16:59+01:00
[File]          File Access Date/Time           : 2019:10:21 08:17:10+01:00
[File]          File Creation Date/Time         : 2019:10:21 08:17:04+01:00
[File]          File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
[File]          File Type                       : MOV
[File]          File Type Extension             : mov
[File]          MIME Type                       : video/quicktime
[QuickTime]     Major Brand                     : Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)
[QuickTime]     Minor Version                   : 0.0.0
[QuickTime]     Compatible Brands               : qt
[QuickTime]     Movie Data Size                 : 179596094
[QuickTime]     Movie Data Offset               : 36
[QuickTime]     Movie Header Version            : 0
[QuickTime]     Create Date                     : 2019:10:17 14:03:25
[QuickTime]     Modify Date                     : 2019:10:17 14:03:53
[QuickTime]     Time Scale                      : 600
[QuickTime]     Duration                        : 27.29 s
[QuickTime]     Preferred Rate                  : 1
[QuickTime]     Preferred Volume                : 100.00%
[QuickTime]     Preview Time                    : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Preview Duration                : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Poster Time                     : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Selection Time                  : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Selection Duration              : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Current Time                    : 0 s
[QuickTime]     Next Track ID                   : 5
[QuickTime]     Track Header Version            : 0
[QuickTime]     Track Create Date               : 2019:10:17 14:03:25
[QuickTime]     Track Modify Date               : 2019:10:17 14:03:53
[QuickTime]     Track ID                        : 1
[QuickTime]     Track Duration                  : 27.29 s
[QuickTime]     Track Layer                     : 0
[QuickTime]     Track Volume                    : 0.00%
[QuickTime]     Image Width                     : 3840
[QuickTime]     Image Height                    : 2160
[QuickTime]     Clean Aperture Dimensions       : 3840x2160
[QuickTime]     Production Aperture Dimensions  : 3840x2160
[QuickTime]     Encoded Pixels Dimensions       : 3840x2160
[QuickTime]     Graphics Mode                   : ditherCopy
[QuickTime]     Op Color                        : 32768 32768 32768
[QuickTime]     Compressor ID                   : hvc1
[QuickTime]     Source Image Width              : 3840
[QuickTime]     Source Image Height             : 2160
[QuickTime]     X Resolution                    : 72
[QuickTime]     Y Resolution                    : 72
[QuickTime]     Compressor Name                 : HEVC
[QuickTime]     Bit Depth                       : 24
[QuickTime]     Video Frame Rate                : 59.993
[QuickTime]     Balance                         : 0
[QuickTime]     Audio Format                    : mp4a
[QuickTime]     Audio Channels                  : 1
[QuickTime]     Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16
[QuickTime]     Audio Sample Rate               : 44100
[QuickTime]     Purchase File Format            : mp4a
[QuickTime]     Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
[QuickTime]     Content Describes               : Track 1
[QuickTime]     Media Header Version            : 0
[QuickTime]     Media Create Date               : 2019:10:17 14:03:25
[QuickTime]     Media Modify Date               : 2019:10:17 14:03:53
[QuickTime]     Media Time Scale                : 600
[QuickTime]     Media Duration                  : 27.29 s
[QuickTime]     Media Language Code             : und
[QuickTime]     Gen Media Version               : 0
[QuickTime]     Gen Flags                       : 0 0 0
[QuickTime]     Gen Graphics Mode               : ditherCopy
[QuickTime]     Gen Op Color                    : 32768 32768 32768
[QuickTime]     Gen Balance                     : 0
[QuickTime]     Handler Class                   : Data Handler
[QuickTime]     Handler Vendor ID               : Apple
[QuickTime]     Handler Description             : Core Media Data Handler
[QuickTime]     Meta Format                     : mebx
[QuickTime]     Handler Type                    : Metadata Tags
[QuickTime]     GPS Coordinates                 : 36 deg 6' 23.04" N, 115 deg 10' 15.96" W, 640.246 m Above Sea Level
[QuickTime]     Make                            : Apple
[QuickTime]     Model                           : iPhone X
[QuickTime]     Software                        : 13.1.2
[QuickTime]     Creation Date                   : 2019:10:17 07:03:25-07:00
[Composite]     Image Size                      : 3840x2160
[Composite]     Megapixels                      : 8.3
[Composite]     Avg Bitrate                     : 52.7 Mbps
[Composite]     GPS Altitude                    : 640.246 m
[Composite]     GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
[Composite]     GPS Latitude                    : 36 deg 6' 23.04" N
[Composite]     GPS Longitude                   : 115 deg 10' 15.96" W
[Composite]     Rotation                        : 0
[Composite]     GPS Position                    : 36 deg 6' 23.04" N, 115 deg 10' 15.96" W
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a suspicion that iOS Photos requires that videos are MOV files for location data to be displayed.

So, I converted the MP4 file to a MOV file using the following command:

```
& "PATH\ffmpeg.exe" -i "PATH\Skydive_OpenShot_ExifTool_Test.mp4" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mov "PATH\Skydive_OpenShot_ExifTool_Test.mov"
```

Then I added the metadata / tags to the MOV file using the following command:

```
& "PATH\exiftool.exe" `
"-QuickTime:CreationDate=2019:10:16 12:00:00-07:00" `
"-QuickTime:GPSCoordinates=35 56 57.2 N, 114 51 28.3 W" `
"PATH\Skydive_OpenShot_ExifTool_Test.mov"
```

This worked perfectly as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this working example — I'm trying to do something similar and this worked! Note that writing to the `QuickTime:CreationDate` tag seems to actually output to `QuickTime:Keys:CreationDate` (and, notably for me, doesn't modify any of the `QuickTime:Track1` dates), but the Photos app seems to preferentially use the `Quick(time:Keys:CreationDate` tag if it exists.